# How to fix error when calculating difference between first and last date for each user?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, date-difference

I want to calculate the difference between the first touch-point of a user's journey and the last touch-point of a user's journey, and that for all journeys.

Here is a (short) example of the data `CJ`:

```
PurchaseID   timestamp                date
1            2016-03-12 22:18:34      2016-03-12
1            2016-03-13 05:25:49      2016-03-13
2            2015-07-18 13:00:38      2015-07-18
2            2015-08-07 19:16:59      2015-08-07
2            2015-11-03 12:31:35      2015-11-03
...
```

I want to create a new variable `difference` which is the difference between the first and last date of each Purchase ID.

What I tried and should work according to other articles on this site, is the following:

```
# difference 
CJ <- data.table(CJ)
CJ[, difference := max(timestamp) - min(timestamp), by = PurchaseID]
```

This gave an error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(CJ, , `:=`(diff, max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)),  : 
  unused argument (by = PurchaseID)
```

The same error occurs when I use only the variable `date`.
In a subset of my data, this error did not occur. So far, I cannot find the underlying cause. Any thoughts?

In addition, the output of `dput`

```
> dput(head(CJgroup))
structure(list(UserID = c(9558L, 9558L, 9558L, 9657L, 1L, 1L), 
    PurchaseID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), timestamp = structure(c(1457817514, 
    1457843149, 1457868381, 1437217238, 1438967819, 1446550295
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Amsterdam"), 
    duration = c(5.786, 65.725, 6.492, 57, 120, 459), device = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("FIXED", "MOBILE"), class = "factor"), 
    touchpoint = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 1L), purchase_own = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), purchase_any = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), MobilePanel = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), FixedPanel = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 17L), CIT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FIT = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), T1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), T2 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), T3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0), T5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T7 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0), T8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T9 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), T10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), T13 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T14 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), T15 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T16 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    T18 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T19 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T20 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T21 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T22 = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), devicemobile = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), devicefixed = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1), purchase_comp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), date = structure(c(16872, 
    16873, 16873, 16634, 16654, 16742), class = "Date"), POS_comp = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), POS_own = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CountTP = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It works fine for me. I'm using _data.table 1.11.4_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution using the `dplyr` package instead of `data.table`.

Then you can do the following

```
library(dplyr)


CJgroup %>% select(PurchaseID, date) %>% 
  group_by(PurchaseID) %>% 
  summarise(difference = as.numeric(max(date) - min(date)))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  PurchaseID difference
       <int>      <dbl>
1          1          1
2          2          0
3          3          0
4          4          0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and editing my question to improve it. I tried your solution, but it results in only one line: 
```> CJgroup %>% group_by(PurchaseID) %>% 
+   summarise(difference = as.numeric(max(date) - min(date)))
  difference
1        519```

Comment: I added your requested result

Comment: Thanks! The outcome is now the same as you showed earlier. I will now simply merge on ```PurchaseID``` and have it included in my dataset. Thanks again!

Comment: glad I could help